# post_date_gmt and post_date

Tags: wp-insert-post, date-time

I am inserting posts programmatically using wp_insert_post. A typical call would look like this:

```
$news_item = array (
    'post_title' => $titleField,
    'post_content' => $retrieve_result['content'],
    'post_status' => 'pending',
    'post_author' => $user->ID,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_date_gmt' => $post_date_gmt
);

$post_id =  wp_insert_post( $news_item );
```

My question is about the parameter post_date_gmt, is this a correct use? Should I use post_date instead? What value is displayed on the screen? I need explanation of both. Documentation does not offer much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments in the `WP_Post` class in [`wp-includes/post.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L0):

> You can set the post date manually, by setting the values for 'post_date' and 'post_date_gmt' keys.

So if you're adding a post programmatically, and you want a date attached, you should set both keys. (If you leave them blank, WordPress will use the appropriate current date for both.)